# how to print value of array element as alert in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am console logging the value of 0th element of an array which is coming from the backend.

My question is how can i use that value and print an alert message on my html page.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterService } from '../../services/register.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 model: any = {};
 
  tiles = [
    {text: 'Four', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'}
  ];
  constructor(private auth: RegisterService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  registerUser(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault()
    const errors = []
    const target = event.target
    const username = target.querySelector('#username').value
    const email = target.querySelector('#email').value
    const dob = target.querySelector('#date').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value
    var test;    

      this.auth.registerUser(username,email,dob, password).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if(data[0].success) {
            console.log(data[0].success) // this data[0] i need to be on html page
        }else{
        }
      })
  

    console.log(username,email,dob,  password)
   
   
  }

}
```

i want the data[0] to be printed on html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your data with some variable then you will be able to access this into view like this -

```
this.auth.registerUser(username,email,dob, password).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if(data[0].success) {
            this.yourData = data[0].success // this data[0] i need to be on html page
        }else{
        }
      });
```

and bind in expression in HTML like this -

```
{{yourData}}
```